# Rails Convert Percentage Value on Edit Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following callback and method in my `Customer` model.

```
before_save :convert_commission_percentage

def convert_commission_percentage
  self.commission= commission.to_f/100.to_f
end
```

This allows the user to input a percentage as `45` and store it as `.45`.  However, on edit, the field for this percentage is then displayed as `.45` on the edit form, causing that number to be divided by 100 again on update.  Is there a way to keep this from happening by displaying the edit field as `45`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Why store converted value, why not store whatever the user inputs without modification.  `commission_percentage` might be a better name.  You could create an alias `commission` to `commission_percentage` with `alias_attribute :commission, :commission_percentage` if you'd like to use `commission` attribute instead of `commission_percentage` attribute in your application.
2. Using `after_initialize` callback:

   ```
   before_save :convert_commission_percentage

   after_initialize do 
     commission = commission.to_f * 100
   end

   def convert_commission_percentage
     self.commission= commission.to_f/100.to_f
   end
   ```
3. Through getters and setters:

   ```
   def commission=(value)
     write_attribute :commission, value.to_f/100
   end

   def commision
     read_attribute(:commission).to_f * 100
   end
   ```

Comment: I think I'm going with option 2.  My thought is it will be easier to do mathematical calculations if it is stored in the database as `.45`.  That way I don't have to convert it every time I do math on it. Thoughts?  Renaming the attribute is not a problem.  `commission_percentage` is a much better attribute name.