# Rails 4 after_initialize Only on Edit method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

Right now I have the following code utilizing a callback.  How can I conditionally restrict this to occur on the edit form?  Currently it works on the edit form, but is also messing up calculations on other portions of my application.

customer.rb

```
after_initialize :convert_commission_percentage   

def convert_commission_percentage
  self.commission_percentage= commission_percentage.to_f/100.to_f
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for [`persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F):

```
after_initialize :convert_commission_percentage   

def convert_commission_percentage
  self.commission_percentage= commission_percentage.to_f/100.to_f if persisted?
end
```

Or as @willmanduffy recommends:

```
after_initialize :convert_commission_percentage, if: :persisted?   

def convert_commission_percentage
  self.commission_percentage= commission_percentage.to_f/100.to_f
end
```

Comment: You can go one further and do after_intitialize :convert_commission_percentage, if: :persisted? Though I think this is a chief example of issues with callbacks: http://adequate.io/culling-the-activerecord-lifecycle

Comment: @willmanduffy, thanks for the link.  It was a good read. I liked how he stressed about unit tests becoming integration tests.  But I believe that callbacks are great features which of course could be organized in a way that makes the individual calls within it's definition unit testable?

Comment: Is there a better way to change a value of an edit field without using a callback?  What are my other options?

Comment: This question is where I came up with this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533935/rails-convert-percentage-value-on-edit-form